# Atl service not registering

Tags: windows, service, atl

I'm trying to register an atl service using

ExeName.exe /service

as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74y2334x(VS.80).aspx

After doing so though, it's not appearing in my services control panel (the one that I get to by typing Services in the start box on vista).

I've tried to dig through the atl code to see where it handles the /service switch, but can't find it, although I can find code to handle /RegServer and /UnregServer

This used to work, I've somehow managed to register this service before. But, now I've moved its location and can't get it registered again. When I run ExeName.exe /service, it does start up as a Local Server if I do a /RegServer first, but I want it installed as a service.

Am I missing something, and do you know where the handling of the /service switch is done?

Comment: the switch should be /regserver and /unregserver. I had a similar issue on windows 2008 and worked fine when i changed casing... weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you haven't accidentally typed some characters in the name of the function ParseCommandLine in class CAtlServiceModuleT defined in atlbase.h

If you do so, there's a version of this function also in the base class which will mean eveything will compile nicely, and it could take you all day to spot this daft mistake!

;-)

Answer (score 2):

Running with the CAtlServiceModule::Install method out of the box, you must use the correct capitals on each argument - "/Service", "/UnregServer", etc.

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark:  Are you running on Vista?  If so make sure you are running with full admin privleges.  Otherwise it's possible you're registering this app via virtualization.

Comment: Good suggestion, I've just double checked my privileges, and I think I've got all the appropriate admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

Same as JaredPar did, try command with Power Shell with full admin privileges.